# Convert working VueJS component to ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

I have a Vue [component](https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/d6vashmu/6/) that works just fine. Now I'm trying to convert that code to ReactJS [equivalent](https://jsfiddle.net/iamanoopchandran/d4g19zo9/4/). My attempt on React

```
 var ticksArray = Array.apply(null, {length: 27}).map(Number.call, Number);
 export default class Timer extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    angle:250,
    minangle:0,
    maxangle:270,
    xDirection:"",
    yDirection:"",
    oldX:0,
    dragging: false
  }
}
onMousedown(){
  this.setState({dragging : true});
}
onMouseup(){
  this.setState({dragging : false});
}
onMousemove(e){
    if(!this.state.dragging)
      return;
    this.setState({
      xDirection : this.state.oldX < e.pageX ? 'right' : 'left',
      oldX:e.pageX,
      yDirection: this.state.xDirection === 'left' ? 'down' : 'up'
    });
    if(this.state.yDirection === 'up' && this.state.angle + 2 <= 
    this.state.maxangle)
        this.setState({angle:this.state.angle += 2})
    else if(this.state.yDirection === 'down' && this.state.angle - 2 >= 
    this.state.minangle)
        this.setState({angle:this.state.angle -= 2})
}
knobStyle(){
  return {
    'transform':'rotate('+this.state.angle+'deg)'
    }
}
activeTicks(){
  return (Math.round(this.state.angle / 10) + 1);
}
currentValue(){
  return Math.round((this.state.angle/270)*100) + '%'
}
componentDidMount(){
  document.addEventListener('mouseup',this.state.onMouseup)
  document.addEventListener('mousemove',this.state.onMousemove)
}
render() {
    var tickDivs = ticksArray.map(function(item) {
        return (
            <div key={item} className="tick"></div>
        );
    });
    return (
        <div id="timer">
            <div className="knob-surround">
                <div className="knob"></div>
                <span className="min">Min</span>
                <span className="max">Max</span>
                <div className="ticks" className="n <= activeTicks ? 
    'activetick' : ''">
                    {tickDivs}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It's not working. I'm missing something. I'm assuming the problem lies in this code bit.

```
<div className="ticks" className="n <= activeTicks ? 
        'activetick' : ''">
```

Please help fix this.

Comment: React uses the following syntax: className={n <= activeTicks ? 
    'activetick' : ''}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this here instead of comment:

1. React uses the following syntax:

   `className={n <= activeTicks ? 'activetick' : ''}`
2. In componentDidMount you assign handlers in a wrong way, should be like:

   `document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseup)`

   Note here that handler is not a part of your state. And the corresponding definition of the handler:

   `private onMouseup = () => {...}`

   The reason to store reference for the event handler instead of having class method - see in #3
3. Do not forget to unsubscribe your event handlers in `componentWillUnmount` like this:

   `window.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseup);`

UPDATE:

Here is an example working without using arrow functions: https://jsfiddle.net/6dnrLw4n/4/

Comment: I'm getting a Syntax error.
`webpackHotDevClient.js:233 Error in ./src/components/Timer.js
Syntax error: C:/Users/admin/Documents/GitHub/....../Timer.js: Unexpected token (19:12)

  17 |       this.setState({dragging : true});
  18 |     }
> 19 |     private onMouseup() =>{
     |             ^
  20 |       this.setState({dragging : false});
  21 |     }
  22 |     onMousemove(e){

 @ ./src/App.js 16:13-42`

Comment: Are you sure you have not missed `=` sign after onMouseup, like I has wrote above: `private onMouseup = () => {...}`

Comment: I changed it back to `onMouseup () {...}` and now I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dragging' of undefined
    at onMousemove (Timer.js:23)`

Comment: That is because in that way you are loosing 'this'. Use arrow functions to keep it (or alternatively `bind` - but I would stick to arrow functions)

Comment: Same issue..
`Error in ./src/components/Timer.js
Syntax error: C:/Users/admin/Documents/GitHub/............/Timer.js: Unexpected token (19:12)

  17 |       this.setState({dragging : true});
  18 |     }
> 19 |     private onMouseup = () =>{
     |             ^
  20 |       this.setState({dragging : false});
  21 |     }
  22 |     onMousemove(e){

 @ ./src/App.js 16:13-42`

Comment: Ok. it looks like you are targeting javascript standard that does not yet have arrow functions support. In this case just leave your `private onMouseup` member unasigned when it is declared. And then in constructor set its value to function with bound `this` (for explanation you can check this article https://www.sitepoint.com/bind-javascripts-this-keyword-react/)

Comment: Here is updated fiddle with working event handlers: https://jsfiddle.net/6dnrLw4n/3/ note that I have not fixed the logic itself - this is something you have to finish.

Comment: Super..it is working. `https://jsfiddle.net/iamanoopchandran/6dnrLw4n/5/`