# HTML Custom Element In React

Tags: css, reactjs, vue.js

I'm a front-end developer who just got off the job.
I'm portting Vue.js project to React. but I have a problem.

## SCSS Code

```
px-contents {
    margin:30px auto;
    

    px-title{
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    &.favGames {
      position: relative;
      margin: 40px auto 0;

      .btn_more_text {
        font-size: 13px;

        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
    }

    &.exchange__favOrder {
      height: calc(100% - 10px);
    }
  }
```

## Vue Code

```
<px-contents class="favGames">
...
</px-contents>
```

Our designer created a custom element with CSS like this.
Can I use this element in React?

If i use  element in react.
react throws me an error like 
`Property 'px-title' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'`

Sorry for my poor English Skill.

Comment: Please post code in words instead of images :)

Comment: Follow [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guideline to get better answers.

Comment: Bro we are unaware what actually `<px-contents>` looks like. of course we can convert any vuejs code to reactjs or angular. We just need to implement the logic in component, rest all are same

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733701/convert-working-vuejs-component-to-reactjs

Comment: thanks ^^7 but SCSS code and that declaration..

This is all ...

Comment: But if i look at that component in Chrome Developer Tools, it's not in the <div> but in the <px-contents> tag. It's probably related to the `html custom element`. I don't know how to use the html custom element in react.